# Remove event before remove DOM element everytime

Tags: javascript, dom, events, garbage-collection

I know that for Javascript events best practice is always remove events that you are no longer use. But what about the event that is attached to a HTML DOM element that I am going to remove, should I remove the event first then remove the DOM element or I can just remove DOM element straight away and not worry about the event that is attached to it?

**Example:**

```
const mainContainerEl = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const addBtnEl = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
const removeBtnEl = document.querySelector('.remove-btn');

const outputTextContent = (e) => {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
}

addBtnEl.addEventListener('click',()=>{

     /* Click to create 5 span DOM elements and add event to each 
          one then append each one of them to mainContainerEl */

     for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
          const newSpanEl = document.createElement('span');
          newSpanEl.textContent = i;
          newSpanEl.addEventListener('click', outputTextContent);
          mainContainerEl.append(newSpanEl);
     };
});



/* Should I do something like this? */

removeBtnEl.addEventListener('click',()=>{
     if(mainContainerEl.firstChild){
          const mainContainerElChildren = [...mainContainerEl.children];
          mainContainerElChildren.forEach((childEl)=>{

               /* Remove event first*/
               childEl.removeEventListener('click',outputTextContent);
               /* After the event is removed, remove the element */
               childEl.remove();

          }); 
     }
});
```

If I don't remove the event first and just remove the DOM element straight away, is the event going to get removed after the DOM element is removed(will the garbage collector collects both of the event and the DOM element and released them from the memory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: in your case, for modern browsers, the event would be garbage collected as there is no more reference to the function.

But it's **not guaranteed** that it's safe in all cases.

Example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.onclick = () => {
  const reference = 'reference';
  setInterval(function () {
    console.log("still here: ", reference);
  }, 100);
  button.remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="button">I'll delete myself</button>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Although the node is removed and there is no reference pointing to the event handler, because of JavaScript closure, the handler's scope is still existing in the memory.

In most cases, we can simply remove the node and let garbage collection take care of the event handlers (only modern browsers though, I'm not sure about older IE browsers). But in the cases like `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in a event handler, we should manually take care of removing it to avoid a memory leak. That's why as in your question, 'for Javascript events best practice is always to remove events that you are no longer use'.

Comment: Sorry few questions, 1.what you mean by "because of JavaScript closure, the handler's scope is still existing in the memory.", how do I release it from the memory?? 2. So basically to guarantee that it'll be safe in all cases, I should just always remove event first, then element itself?? 3. For the example above, if I have "setInterval", I also need to clear it too right? cause I don't think after remove the event and element itself, "setInterval" clears too. thanks :)

Comment: Hi @It'sTimeToSleep sure. For simple functions like yours, it doesn't contain `setTimeout` and `setInterval` so it would simply be garbage collected when there is no more reference to it. What I meant is just for special cases like `setInterval`. 
"So basically to guarantee that it'll be safe in all cases, I should just always remove event first, then element itself" is correct as it's always considered as the best practice. 
"For the example above, if I have "setInterval", I also need to clear it too right?" is also true, we need to manually call `clearInterval(intervalId)` in cleanup steps

Comment: @It'sTimeToSleep In short, it's not mandatory to remove event handlers but a good practice. And `setTimeout` or `setInterval` definitely needs special clean up steps.

Comment: By "there is no more reference to it", do you mean, if inside of my function is not using any outside function scope's & global scope's variables/datas and outside scope & global scope is also not using any variables/datas from inside of my function?? thanks :)

Comment: @It'sTimeToSleep I think it's better to be 'outer scope not using any variables/datas from inside my function, and not maintaining reference to the function itself'